# How does hostname change to hostname.local on a pi?

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, hostname

With a fresh install of Raspberry pi os, the device is accessible on the local network under the hostname `raspberrypi.local`.

On the device, `/etc/hostname` contains `raspberrypi` and if I `echo foo.bar >/etc/hostname` and reboot, the device is accessible under the hostname `foo.bar.local`.

Where does the `.local` suffix get added, and how can I stop that? (I want to access the device under the hostname `foo.bar`).

Comment: changing the name from `.local` will likely stop Avahi from routing properly.

Comment: Have a read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS